# MySQL : Avoid Temporary/Filesort Caused by GROUP BY Clause in Views

Tags: mysql, view, sorting, temporary-tables

I'm planning on creating a view using this SQL SELECT, but the explain for it shows it's using temporary and using filesort. I can't figure out what indices I need in order to fix this problem. Mostly, I'm wondering why it's using filesort instead of using an index to sort.

Table bn_ms_gt_generaltransaction has 7 million records
Table bn_pd_mp_masterprofile has few hundred records
Table bn_pd_sc_scheme also has few hundred records

Here are create table statements:

```
    CREATE TABLE `bn_ms_gt_generaltransaction` (
      `GNTRDATE` date NOT NULL,
      `GNTRNUMBER` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
      `GNTRSUBNUMBER` decimal(5,0) NOT NULL,
      `ORGACODE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `LOCACODE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `PRODCODE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `SCHEMCODE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `BKMSNUMBER` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `TRANCODE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `GNTRVALUEDAT` date NOT NULL,
      `GNTRDRCR` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `GLACCODE` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `CURRCODE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `GNTRAMTFC` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
      `GNTRSTATUS` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `TMODCODE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ORGACODE`,`LOCACODE`,`GNTRDATE`,`GNTRNUMBER`,`GNTRSUBNUMBER`),
      KEY `CC10921796764` (`TMODCODE`),
      KEY `SQL0407170412326` (`TRANCODE`),
      KEY `SQL0407170412328` (`CURRCODE`),
      KEY `SQL0407170412329` (`ORGACODE`,`GLACCODE`),
      KEY `GNTRDRCR` (`GNTRDRCR`),
      KEY `GLACCODE` (`GLACCODE`),
      KEY `GT_ACC_NUM` (`PRODCODE`,`SCHEMCODE`,`BKMSNUMBER`),
      KEY `GT_PK` (`GNTRDATE`,`GNTRNUMBER`,`GNTRSUBNUMBER`),
      KEY `GT_EFFECTDATE` (`GNTREFFECTDAT`),
      KEY `GT_GL_CODE` (`ORGACODE`,`LOCACODE`,`CURRCODE`,`GLACCODE`),
      KEY `INDEX_GNTRDATE` (`GNTRDATE`),
      KEY `INDEX_GNTRVALUEDAT` (`GNTRVALUEDAT`),
      KEY `GT_VOUCHER` (`GNTRDATE`,`GNTRNUMBER`),
      KEY `REPORT_INDEX_2` (`PRODCODE`,`SCHEMCODE`,`BKMSNUMBER`,`GNTRDATE`,`TRANCODE`,`GLACCODE`,`GNTRSTATUS`,`SGT_REVERSALTAG`,`GNTRAMTFC`),
      KEY `INDEX_LRDL_GROUPBY` (`PRODCODE`,`SCHEMCODE`,`BKMSNUMBER`,`GNTRDATE`,`GNTRVALUEDAT`,`GNTREFFECTDAT`,`GNTRNUMBER`,`TRANCODE`,`TMODCODE`),
      KEY `INDEX_LRDL_GROUPBY_LOOSE` (`PRODCODE`,`SCHEMCODE`,`BKMSNUMBER`,`GNTRDATE`,`GNTRVALUEDAT`,`GNTREFFECTDAT`,`GNTRNUMBER`,`TRANCODE`,`TMODCODE`,`GNTRAMTFC`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


    CREATE TABLE `bn_pd_mp_masterprofile` (
      `PRODCODE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `ORGACODE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `GLACCODE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `PPC_PRCGCODE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`PRODCODE`),
      KEY `SQL040126114206120` (`PPC_PRCGCODE`),
      KEY `SQL040126114206101` (`ORGACODE`,`GLACCODE`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    CREATE TABLE `bn_pd_sc_scheme` (
      `PRODCODE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `SCHEMCODE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `ORGACODE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `GLACCODE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `CURRCODE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `SCHEPURPOSE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `CODE_PENALTY` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`PRODCODE`,`SCHEMCODE`),
      KEY `SQL040126114217543` (`CURRCODE`),
      KEY `CC1318422668625` (`PST_PSTYCODE`),
      KEY `SQL040126114217560` (`ORGACODE`,`GLACCODE`),
      KEY `CC1205848198000` (`ORGACODE`,`CODE_PENALTY`),
      CONSTRAINT `CC1205848198000` FOREIGN KEY (`ORGACODE`, `CODE_PENALTY`) REFERENCES `pr_gl_ca_account` (`ORGACODE`, `GLACCODE`),
      CONSTRAINT `SQL040126114217543` FOREIGN KEY (`CURRCODE`) REFERENCES `pr_gn_cr_currency` (`CURRCODE`),
      CONSTRAINT `SQL040126114217560` FOREIGN KEY (`ORGACODE`, `GLACCODE`) REFERENCES `pr_gl_ca_account` (`ORGACODE`, `GLACCODE`),
      CONSTRAINT `SQL040126114217562` FOREIGN KEY (`PRODCODE`) REFERENCES `bn_pd_mp_masterprofile` (`PRODCODE`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And following are two views select

```
    SELECT
      `a`.`PRODCODE`      AS `PRODCODE`,
      `a`.`SCHEMCODE`     AS `SCHEMCODE`,
      `a`.`BKMSNUMBER`    AS `BKMSNUMBER`,
      `a`.`GNTRDATE`      AS `GNTRDATE`,
      `a`.`GNTRVALUEDAT`  AS `GNTRVALUEDAT`,
      `a`.`GNTREFFECTDAT` AS `GNTREFFECTDAT`,
      `a`.`GNTRNUMBER`    AS `GNTRNUMBER`,
      `a`.`TRANCODE`      AS `TRANCODE`,
      `a`.`TMODCODE`      AS `TMODCODE`,
      (CASE WHEN ((`a`.`TRANCODE` = '29') AND (`a`.`GNTRDRCR` = 'DR') AND (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`GLACCODE`)) THEN COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRAMTFC`,0) END) AS `DISB_AMOUNT`,
      (CASE WHEN ((`a`.`TRANCODE` = '29') AND (`a`.`GNTRDRCR` = 'CR') AND (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`GLACCODE`)) THEN COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRAMTFC`,0) END) AS `DISB_AMOUNT_REV`,
      (CASE WHEN ((`a`.`TRANCODE` IN ('30','32')) AND (`a`.`GNTRDRCR` = 'CR') AND (COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRSTATUS`,'P')  'C') AND (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`GLACCODE`)) THEN COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRAMTFC`,0) END) AS `PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT`,
      (CASE WHEN ((`a`.`TRANCODE` IN ('30','32')) AND (`a`.`GNTRDRCR` = 'CR') AND (COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRSTATUS`,'P') = 'C') AND (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`GLACCODE`)) THEN COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRAMTFC`,0) END) AS `PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT_CANCEL`,
      (CASE WHEN ((`a`.`TRANCODE` IN ('30','32')) AND (`a`.`GNTRDRCR` = 'DR') AND (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`GLACCODE`)) THEN COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRAMTFC`,0) END) AS `PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT_REV`,
      (CASE WHEN ((`a`.`TRANCODE` IN ('30','73','32')) AND (`a`.`GNTRDRCR` = 'CR') AND (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`SCHEPURPOSE`)) THEN COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRAMTFC`,0) END) AS `MARKUP_AMOUNT`,
      (CASE WHEN ((`a`.`TRANCODE` IN ('30','73','32')) AND (`a`.`GNTRDRCR` = 'DR') AND (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`SCHEPURPOSE`)) THEN COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRAMTFC`,0) END) AS `MARKUP_AMOUNT_REV`,
      (CASE WHEN ((`a`.`TRANCODE` IN ('30','55','32')) AND (`a`.`GNTRDRCR` = 'CR') AND (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`CODE_PENALTY`)) THEN COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRAMTFC`,0) END) AS `OTHER_AMOUNT`,
      (CASE WHEN ((`a`.`TRANCODE` IN ('30','55','32')) AND (`a`.`GNTRDRCR` = 'DR') AND (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`CODE_PENALTY`)) THEN COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRAMTFC`,0) END) AS `OTHER_AMOUNT_REV`
    FROM ((`bn_ms_gt_generaltransaction` `a`
        JOIN `bn_pd_mp_masterprofile` `mp`
          ON (((`mp`.`PRODCODE` = `a`.`PRODCODE`)
               AND (`mp`.`PPC_PRCGCODE` = 'LOAN'))))
       JOIN `bn_pd_sc_scheme` `sc`
         ON (((`a`.`PRODCODE` = `sc`.`PRODCODE`)
              AND (`a`.`SCHEMCODE` = `sc`.`SCHEMCODE`))))
    WHERE ((`a`.`TRANCODE` IN('29','30','55','73','32'))
           AND ((`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`GLACCODE`)
                 OR (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`SCHEPURPOSE`)
                 OR (`a`.`GLACCODE` = `sc`.`CODE_PENALTY`))
           AND ((COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRSTATUS`,'P')  'C')
                 OR ((COALESCE(`a`.`GNTRSTATUS`,'P') = 'C')
                     AND (`a`.`GNTRVALUEDAT` = `a`.`GNTRDATE`)
                     AND (`a`.`GNTRVALUEDAT`  `a`.`GNTREFFECTDAT`))))
```

```
    SELECT
      `a`.`DMP_PRODCODE`      AS `DMP_PRODCODE`,
      `a`.`DCS_SCHEMCODE`     AS `DCS_SCHEMCODE`,
      `a`.`MBM_BKMSNUMBER`    AS `MBM_BKMSNUMBER`,
      `a`.`SGT_GNTRDATE`      AS `SGT_GNTRDATE`,
      `a`.`SGT_GNTRVALUEDAT`  AS `SGT_GNTRVALUEDAT`,
      `a`.`SGT_GNTREFFECTDAT` AS `SGT_GNTREFFECTDAT`,
      `a`.`SGT_GNTRNUMBER`    AS `SGT_GNTRNUMBER`,
      `a`.`PTR_TRANCODE`      AS `PTR_TRANCODE`,
      `a`.`PTM_TMODCODE`      AS `PTM_TMODCODE`,
      SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`DISB_AMOUNT`,0)) AS `DISB_AMOUNT`,
      SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`DISB_AMOUNT_REV`,0)) AS `DISB_AMOUNT_REV`,
      (SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`DISB_AMOUNT`,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`DISB_AMOUNT_REV`,0))) AS `TOTAL_DISB`,
      SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT`,0)) AS `PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT`,
      SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT_REV`,0)) AS `PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT_REV`,
      SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT_CANCEL`,0)) AS `PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT_CANCEL`,
      (SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT`,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT_REV`,0))) AS `TOTAL_PRINCIPAL`,
      SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`MARKUP_AMOUNT`,0)) AS `MARKUP_AMOUNT`,
      SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`MARKUP_AMOUNT_REV`,0)) AS `MARKUP_AMOUNT_REV`,
      (SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`MARKUP_AMOUNT`,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`MARKUP_AMOUNT_REV`,0))) AS `TOTAL_MARKUP`,
      SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`OTHER_AMOUNT`,0)) AS `OTHER_AMOUNT`,
      SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`OTHER_AMOUNT_REV`,0)) AS `OTHER_AMOUNT_REV`,
      (SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`OTHER_AMOUNT`,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(`a`.`OTHER_AMOUNT_REV`,0))) AS `TOTAL_OTHER`
    FROM `test_view` `a`
    GROUP BY `a`.`DMP_PRODCODE`,`a`.`DCS_SCHEMCODE`,`a`.`MBM_BKMSNUMBER`,`a`.`SGT_GNTRDATE`,`a`.`SGT_GNTRVALUEDAT`,`a`.`SGT_GNTREFFECTDAT`,`a`.`SGT_GNTRNUMBER`,`a`.`PTR_TRANCODE`,`a`.`PTM_TMODCODE`$$
```

The second view uses the first.

Output from explain:

```
    id          select_type     table           type            possible_keys           key         key_len         ref         rows            Extra
    1           PRIMARY                   ALL                                                         3564            
    2           DERIVED         mp          ref         PRIMARY,SQL040126114206120  SQL040126114206120          63          const           3           Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
    2           DERIVED         sc          ref           PRIMARY           PRIMARY         62          mp.PRODCODE         2           
    2           DERIVED         a           ref         SQL0407170412326,PCA_GLACCODE,GT_ACC_NUM,REPORT_INDEX_2,INDEX_LRDL_GROUPBY,INDEX_LRDL_GROUPBY_LOOSE         INDEX_LRDL_GROUPBY          126         mp.PRODCODE,sc.SCHEMCODE            594         Using index condition; Using where
```

Now, the top derived table shows **using temporary; using filesort**.
Even creating index doesn't help. I tried to create index on group by for **loose index** but doesn't work. AM I missing something?
I have explored about it and found many workarounds but none fits my example. Some suggest to do **aggregation in subquery** before join which is not possible as MySQL doesn't allow subquery in FROM clause of **VIEW**.
Creating another view doesn't work as I need to filter records before summation.
So, can someone help me with fixing the issue.

Comment: Confusion: Where is `PPC_PRCGCODE`  defined ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I have updated the product table with missing column. Secondly, Even if I execute the above two queries by making first as subquery of the second. Still I can see temporary/filesort. So, Can we remove that from it because I have rewritten the view as single query?

Answer (score 1):

## OBSERVATION #1

The MySQL Documentation gives you the [***Restrictions on Views***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-restrictions.html)

> - It is not possible to create an index on a view.
> - Indexes can be used for views processed using the merge algorithm. However, a view that is processed with the temptable algorithm is unable to take advantage of indexes on its underlying tables (although indexes can be used during generation of the temporary tables).
>
> Subqueries cannot be used in the FROM clause of a view.

Therefore

- The result set of a View would be some temp table used for row-by-row retrieval
- There is no existing mechanism to index the result set coming from a view

Creating indexes only help the underlying base tables within the JOIN a the View, not the View itself.

## OBSERVATION #2

You mentioned this

> Some suggest to do aggregation in subquery before join which is not possible as MySQL doesn't allow subquery in FROM clause.

That's not true. I have a post in StackOverflow ([**Fetching a Single Row from Join Table**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983156/fetching-a-single-row-from-join-table/6023217#6023217)) that clearly demonstrates doing an aggregation in a subquery followed by all kinds of JOINs to that subquery.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I didn't mention that its about Views i.e. we cannot use subquery in FROM clause of views. I am updating question with correction and PPC_PRCGCODE column.